# How to use Java 8 Streams to Implement zip in specific way?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Streams API to implement a zip function that takes an unbounded number of int[]'s as an argument; takes the i'th element from each; puts those in a Tuple (obviously a custom Tuple object is needed - which I have) and returns a list of Tuples (i.e. List).

Essentially, for:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ 4, 5, 6 }
```

the proposed method should return:
`[ Tuple(1, 4), Tuple(2, 5), Tuple(3, 6) ]` as a `java.util.List<Tuple>`

Here is a function that does what I'm trying to do in a "normal" way:

```
/**
 * Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
 * from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is
 * truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
 *
 * @param args  the array of ints to be wrapped in {@link Tuple}s
 * @return a list of tuples
 */
public static List<Tuple> zip(int[]... args) {
    List<Tuple> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
    // Find the array with the minimum size
    int minLength = Arrays.stream(args).map(i -> new Integer(i.length)).min((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)).get();

    for(int i = 0;i < minLength;i++) {
        Tuple.Builder builder = Tuple.builder();
        for(int[] ia : args) {
            builder.add(ia[i]);
        }
        retVal.add(builder.build());
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to create a Stream over the indexes and using `mapToObj` to map each `int` into a `Tuple`. Also, since you already have a `Builder` object, we can utilize it to collect the elements into it.

Supposing we add a method `Tuple.Builder.addAll(Tuple.Builder other)` whose purpose would be to add one builder to another, we could have the following code:

```
public static List<Tuple> zip(int[]... args) {
    // Find the array with the minimum size
    int minLength = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(i -> i.length).min().orElse(0);

    return IntStream.range(0, minLength)
                    .mapToObj(i -> 
                       Arrays.stream(args)
                             .mapToInt(ia -> ia[i])
                             .collect(Tuple::builder, Tuple.Builder::add, Tuple.Builder::addAll)
                             .build()
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

(If you don't want to support parallel execution, you could just throw an exception with `(b1, b2) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); }` and not add the `addAll` method.)

---

As a side-note, the code for finding the minimal array size can be simplified: you don't need to box into an `Integer`, you can just map each array to its length and get the minimum with [`min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--). This returns an `OptionalInt`; instead of getting its value, which might throw an exception if the Stream was empty, I used `orElse(0)` so that, in the case of an empty Stream, an empty list is returned.

Comment: If your `Tuple` type supports creating a tuple from an int array, it might be simpler to replace the `collect(…).build()` part of the inner stream by a simple `toArray()` call and create the tuple from the result.